# Почему атрибут не добавляется в модель?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, controller, jstl

Не судите строго, ошибка в какой-то мелочи наверное. Есть `view.jsp`, кусок интересующего кода вот:

```
<h1 class="tab"> View parts of details  </h1>
<c:if test="${!empty detailList}">
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
        <th width="200">Name</th>
        <th width="80">Required</th>
        <th width="60">Count</th>
        <th width="60">Edit</th>
        <th width="60">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${detailList}" var="detail">
        <tr>
            <td>${detail.name}</td>
            <td>${detail.required}</td>
            <td>${detail.count}</td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${detail.name}/${page}/${detailList.size()}/${nameoflist}'/>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='/delete/${detail.id}/${page}/${detailList.size()}/${nameoflist}'/>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
</c:if>
```

из строки со ссылкой, а конкретно вот этой:

```
<td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${detail.name}/${page}/${detailList.size()}/${nameoflist}'/>">Edit</a></td>
```

Перебрасывает в контроллер, конкретно вот сюда:

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{name}/{page}/{dlist}/{nameoflist}")
public String edit(Model model,
                   @PathVariable("name") String name,
                   @PathVariable("page") int page,
                   @PathVariable("dlist") int dlist,
                   @PathVariable("nameoflist") String nameoflist){
    Detail detailForEdit = serviceClassDetail.findByName(name);

    System.out.println(detailForEdit.getName() + detailForEdit.getId() + detailForEdit.getCount()); 
    String str = serviceClassDetail.creatRedirectForEditDelete(dlist, nameoflist, page);
    model.addAttribute("detailForEdit", detailForEdit);

    return str; // "redirect:/[nameoflist]?=[page]"
}
```

Из которой редиректится обратно в view.

Однако когда я пытаюсь достать там эту переменную, ее там не оказывается вообще. Где, и что я не правильно делаю?

Пытаюсь просмотреть эти данные во вьюхе просто:

```
<c:if test="${detailForEdit != null}">
<a> ${detailForEdit.name} </a>
</c:if>
<a> detailForEdit =  ${detailForEdit.name} </a>
```

**PS:**

**Описание логики:**

при нажатии на `edit`, я знаю какой элемент мне нужно изменить, перехожу в контроллер-гет-маппинг, там достаю данные для изменений и хочу их подставить во вьюху для уже последующих изменений, редиректюсь туда, но туда эти данные через модель не приходят, почему?

Да, sout в контроллере это для проверки, что данные там действительно есть.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но возможно дело в редиректе. Попробуйте просто направить пользоватедя на страницу, без редиректа.

Comment: Дебагер показывает элемент в ModelView который добавляете?

Comment: В дебаггере показывает что в model добавляется элемент, размер = 1. Если направлять просто на страницу, то он добавляет страницу после текущей, в итоге там вылезает что-то типа: http://localhost:8080/edit/%D0%9C%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C/0/10/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спринг никогда не делает редирект на вью, он использует диспатчер сервлет для направления в JSP. Потому, что JSP - это сервлет, который создается автомвтически после компиляции JSP.

Если вы будете использовать шаблонизатор типа thymeleaf или freemarker, или velocity то тогда после обработки контент сразу пишется в ответ и вам не придется перенаправлять один сервлет на другой.

Как использовать шаблонизатор thymeleaf можно почитать [здесь](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html). Что касается freemarker и/или velocity то почитать можно [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch16s04.html). То есть для конкретного шаблонизатора надо выбрать соответствующий вью резолвер.

Если вы еще хотите продолжать использовать JSP для [вью](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html), то вашу проблему лучше всего решать если использовать тэги `<spring>` вместо JSTL. Обратите внимание на то каким образом данные связываются с моделью.

Если вам непонятна суть использования редиректа, то следует почитать здесь каким образом  и когда следует, используя методы POST/GET для запросов, развивать [PRG паттерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Этот паттерн часто используется в CRUD приложениях, когда данные из формы после add/edit сабмитятся в контроллер и и он перенаправляет на другой контроллер для просмотра/показа добавленных/измененных данных.