# Как правильно сделать redirect

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet, redirect

Есть стартовая страница с формой, на которой находятся поля ввода данных и две кнопки типа `submit`. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на одну кнопку, форма перенаправляла  пользователя на страницу `jsp`, а когда нажали на вторую, то на сервлет.

Пытаюсь сделать редирект. Сама форма:

```
 <form name="main form" method="post" action="Servlet" onsubmit="redirect(this)">
<label>Введите функцию</label>
<input type="text" name="function"> <br> 
<label>Введите начальное значения х</label>
<input type="text" name="xmin"> <br>
<label>Введите шаг изминения значения х</label>
<input type="text" name="dx"> <br>
<label>Введите граничное значение х</label>
<input type="text" name="xmax"> <br>
<label>Переадресация на JSP</label>
<input type="submit" name="JSPButton" style="background: brown"></input> <br>
<label>Переадресация на Servlet</label>
<input type="submit" name="ServletButton" style="background: aqua"></input> <br>
```

Перенаправляет пользователя в промежуточный сервлет, в котором я и пытаюсь проверить, на какую из кнопок нажали:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Field;
 import java.util.Enumeration;

 public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    Enumeration fields =request.getParameterNames();
    if (fields.hasMoreElements()){
        while (fields.hasMoreElements()){
            String field = (String) fields.nextElement();
            String name = request.getParameter(field);

            if(name.equals("JSPButton")){
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/LW4_war_exploded/Table.jsp");
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {


}
}
```

Но перенаправления не происходит. При этом ссылка правильная. Если перейти по ней из среды, то страницу открывает. Подскажите, как правильно сделать редирект?

Comment: У тебя не происходит редирект, потому что условие никогда не выполняется. Сравнивай не поле name, а поле field. То есть  field.equals("JSPButton")

Comment: @NarasuOo Спасибо, все работает. Оформите, как ответ, я приму.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881555/204920