# Thymeleaf отказывается работать вместе с контроллером и spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

К сожалению не получается запустить и протестировать систему, thymeleaf отказывается работать, не могу понять где конкретно ошибка. Tomcat запускает аппликацию, но пытаясь перейти localhost:8080/ ( страницы)
получаю ошибку что на странице что в консоле. Такое ощущение что фронт вообще не соединен с бэком.
Прошу отнестись с пониманием к новичку. Вопрос публикую первый раз.  Заранее благодарю!

Прикладываю все скриншоты :
1. скрин : Консоль когда пытаюсь перейти на localhost:8080/ ( моистраницы)
2. скрин : Проэкт собирался через tart.spring.io
3. скрин : Сам контроллер:
4. скрин : Это листбокс для выбора категории
5. скрин : Часть кода Thymeleaf ( моистраницы)
6. скрин : Когда открываю через idea
7. скрин : URL выглядит вот так и видно html файл :
8. скрин : Когда же открываю localhost:8080/ ( мои страницы) то каждая страница выдает ошибку

[image: Консоль когда пытаюсь перейти на localhost:8080/ ( моистраницы)]

[image: Проэкт собирался через tart.spring.io ,]

[image: Сам контроллер:]

[image: Это листбокс для выбора категории]

[image: Часть кода Thymeleaf][image: Когда открываю через idea :]

[image: URL выглядит вот так и видно html файл :]

[image: Когда же открываю localhost:8080/ ( мои страницы) то каждая страница выдает ошибку]

Comment: Код надо текстом, не картинкой. Картинку сложно читать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881555/204920

Answer (score 0):

судя по ошибке, надо смотреть в сторону расположения шаблонов Thymeleaf в ресурсах, они должны находиться в папке src/main/resources/templates

пример шаблона для отображения по пути /request-add файл src/main/resources/templates/add-request.html

рекомендую ознакомиться:

- документация [thymeleaf.org/doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#preface)
- отличная статья от baeldung [spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf)